# Why are some of my Unit Tests being run multiple times?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, resharper

When I run all of the Unit Tests in my solution using Visual Studio's built-in testing engine, I'll see that some tests are run multiple times, while others are only run once:

[Test Result Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHNRu.jpg)

It appears that if there are multiple `TestClass`es in the same file, things get confusing. In this file, for example:

```
[TestClass]
public class AerationEngineTests
{
    protected IAerationEngine aerationEngine;
    protected AerationPackage aerationPackage;
    protected BinPackage bin;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        aerationEngine = new AerationEngine();
        aerationPackage = new AerationPackage();
        bin = new BinPackage();
        bin.Children.Add(new Shell {ShellDiameter = 75, RingCount = 15, RingHeight = RingHeights.RingHeight32});
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldCalculateFloorArea()
    {
        // Arrange


        // Act
        var floorArea = aerationEngine.CalculateFloorArea(aerationPackage, bin);

        // Assert
        floorArea.ShouldBeInRange(4417.86, 4417.87);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldCalculateBinCapacity()
    {
        // Arrange
        aerationPackage.FillType = FillTypes.Peaked;
        var grainDepth = aerationEngine.CalculateGrainDepth(aerationPackage, bin);
        var floorArea = aerationEngine.CalculateFloorArea(aerationPackage, bin);
        var calculations = new FanCalculations {GrainDepth = grainDepth, FloorArea = floorArea};

        // Act
        var binCapacity = aerationEngine.CalculateMaxBinCapacity(calculations);

        // Assert
        binCapacity.ShouldBeInRange(175525.88, 175525.9);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldCalculateTargetAirFlow()
    {
        // Arrange
        aerationPackage.FillType = FillTypes.Peaked;
        aerationPackage.DesiredAirFlow = AirFlowRates.AirFlowOne4th;
        var grainDepth = aerationEngine.CalculateGrainDepth(aerationPackage, bin);
        var floorArea = aerationEngine.CalculateFloorArea(aerationPackage, bin);
        var calculations = new FanCalculations {GrainDepth = grainDepth, FloorArea = floorArea};
        var binCapacity = aerationEngine.CalculateMaxBinCapacity(calculations);
        calculations.MaxBinCapacity = binCapacity;

        // Act
        var airflow = aerationEngine.CalculateTargetAirflow(aerationPackage, calculations);

        // Assert
        airflow.ShouldBeInRange(43881.46, 43881.48);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldCalculateTargetAirFlowPerFan()
    {
        // Arrange
        aerationPackage.FillType = FillTypes.Peaked;
        aerationPackage.DesiredAirFlow = AirFlowRates.AirFlowOne4th;
        aerationPackage.FanCount = 4;
        var grainDepth = aerationEngine.CalculateGrainDepth(aerationPackage, bin);
        var floorArea = aerationEngine.CalculateFloorArea(aerationPackage, bin);
        var calculations = new FanCalculations {GrainDepth = grainDepth, FloorArea = floorArea};
        var binCapacity = aerationEngine.CalculateMaxBinCapacity(calculations);
        calculations.MaxBinCapacity = binCapacity;
        var airflow = aerationEngine.CalculateTargetAirflow(aerationPackage, calculations);
        calculations.TargetAirFlow = airflow;
        // Act
        var flowPerFan = aerationEngine.CalculateTargetAirflowPerFan(aerationPackage, calculations);

        // Assert
        flowPerFan.ShouldBeInRange(10970.3, 10970.4);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldCalculateFloorPressure()
    {
        // Arrange

        // Act
        var floorPressure = aerationEngine.CalculateFloorPressure(aerationPackage, bin);

        // Assert
        floorPressure.ShouldBeInRange(1943.0, 1945.0);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldCalculateTrenchWidth()
    {
        // Arrange
        aerationPackage.FillType = FillTypes.Peaked;
        aerationPackage.DesiredAirFlow = AirFlowRates.AirFlowOne4th;
        aerationPackage.FanCount = 4;
        var grainDepth = aerationEngine.CalculateGrainDepth(aerationPackage, bin);
        var floorArea = aerationEngine.CalculateFloorArea(aerationPackage, bin);
        var calculations = new FanCalculations {GrainDepth = grainDepth, FloorArea = floorArea};
        var binCapacity = aerationEngine.CalculateMaxBinCapacity(calculations);
        calculations.MaxBinCapacity = binCapacity;
        var airflow = aerationEngine.CalculateTargetAirflow(aerationPackage, calculations);
        calculations.TargetAirFlow = airflow;
        var flowPerFan = aerationEngine.CalculateTargetAirflowPerFan(aerationPackage, calculations);
        calculations.TargetAirFlowPerFan = flowPerFan;

        // Act
        var trenchWidth = aerationEngine.CalculateTrenchWidth(calculations);

        // Assert
        trenchWidth.ShouldBe(72);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class CalculateGrainDepthMethod : AerationEngineTests
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public new void TestInitialize()
    {
        base.TestInitialize();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldCalculateLevelFillHeight()
    {
        // Arrange
        aerationPackage.FillType = FillTypes.Level;

        // Act
        var grainDepth = aerationEngine.CalculateGrainDepth(aerationPackage, bin);

        // Assert
        grainDepth.ShouldBe(40.0);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldCalculatePeakedFillHeight()
    {
        // Arrange
        aerationPackage.FillType = FillTypes.Peaked;

        // Act
        var grainDepth = aerationEngine.CalculateGrainDepth(aerationPackage, bin);

        // Assert
        grainDepth.ShouldBeInRange(46.64, 46.66);
    }
}
```

The tests inside of `CalculateGrainDepthMethod` get run once, but the rest of the test methods get run twice, and they're grouped under `CalculateGrainDepthMethod`. See this pic (using ReSharper's tools):

[ReSharper Test result window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGnz0.jpg)

It doesn't appear that there are two testing engines running at the same time, but maybe there are? Or maybe I just structured the tests themselves incorrectly? Does anyone know why these tests would run more than once, and why they'd be grouped under classes to which they don't belong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are inheriting class `CalculateGrainDepthMethod` inherits from `AerationEngineTests`. Because of this tests in class `AerationEngineTests` are executing twice.

```
[TestClass]
public class CalculateGrainDepthMethod : AerationEngineTests
{
```

Either have the dependencies contained in class `CalculateGrainDepthMethod` or create a test helper which initializes these values and use it in both your test classes.

Comment: The second suggestion, "create a test helper which initializes these values", was the one that worked best for my situation. I then made gave the `TestInitialize` methods in the derived classes the `new` keyword and called `base.TestInitialize()`. I'd upvote your answer if I had enough rep. Please, anyone who sees this, give the guy an upvote!